# How do I check if such a person reacted to a message, and move this user to another voicechannel in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How do I check if such a person reacted to a message and move this people to another voice channel in discord.js?

For example:

```
if(idpeoplereact !== "idbot"){
  if(idpeoplereact.react === "✅"){ 
    member.setVoiceChannel(`${idchannel}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: try the ``.awaitReactions()`` function https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `messageReactionAdd` event. For example:

```
let channelID = "29383093093983"; // The Channel ID where the member will be moved

client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => { // When a reaction is added
    if(user.bot) return; // If the user who reacted is a bot, return
    if(reaction.emoji.name !== "✅") return; // If the emoji is not a ✅, return
    let member = reaction.message.guild.members.get(user.id); // Fetch the guild member who added the reaction
    member.setVoiceChannel(reaction.message.guild.channels.get(channelID);
});
```